TabularData from json file print optinal data <Array<Optional<Any>>>
Into swift using TabularData framework. when json contains dictionary with array of value. The column and row is optional.
here is the json for json file:
[
  {
     "firstname":["John", "john2"],
     "surname": ["Doe", "doe2"]
     }, {
     "firstname":["Jane", "Jane2"],
     "surname": ["Doe", "Doe2"]
  }
]

Code using TabularData framework
guard let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "jsondatafile", withExtension: "json") else { return }

var dataframe = try! DataFrame(contentsOfJSONFile: fileUrl)`

here is the print result for dataframe
Rows
▿ base : ┏━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃   ┃ firstname                         ┃ surname                         ┃
┃   ┃ <Array<Optional>>            ┃ <Array<Optional>>          ┃
┡━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ 0 │ [Optional(John), Optional(john2)] │ [Optional(Doe), Optional(doe2)] │
│ 1 │ [Optional(Jane), Optional(Jane2)] │ [Optional(Doe), Optional(Doe2)] │
└───┴───────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
Expected should be :
┏━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃   ┃ fnam              ┃ lnam            ┃
┃   ┃ <Array>   ┃ <Array> ┃
┡━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ 0 │ ["John", "john2"] │ ["Doe", "doe2"] │
│ 1 │ ["Jane", "Jane2"] │ ["Doe", "Doe2"] │
└───┴───────────────────┴─────────────────┘

The DataFrame initialiser fails to infer the type of the column as [String]. I think it only recognises the types declared in JSONType. Every JSON array is treated in the same way, as the array type. When creating the data frame, that column would become of type [Any?]. The implementation doesn't look at the contents of the array to infer a better type.
To achieve the desired result, you would need to manually change the types of the columns.
dataFrame.transformColumn("firstname") { (value: [Any?]) in value as? [String] }
dataFrame.transformColumn("surname") { (value: [Any?]) in value as? [String] }

